# Django: How to handle Settings Keys in database

Tags: python, django

I came across a requirement where I need to save some settings Key, Value in database. So I created a Model with Key, Value fields. Now I want to access these values. First thing that came in my mind I should get value from database. Here is example.

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def get_key_value(cls, key):
        obj = cls.objects.filter(key==key)
        if obj.count() > 0:
            return obj.first().value;

        return None

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'app_settings'
```

I think this is not good idea to hit database every time. I want to save all list in global variable or session.

How can I store data in global?

I dont know is this good approach? Please suggest me better way to do it.

Comment: You can use something like https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You could use some kind of inmemory database like Redis

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to save when you can access the data in settings.py directly?

```
from django.conf import settings

print settings.SOME_VALUE
```

So There is no need to save I believe

Comment: Yeah I know, But I have to put some keys in database. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a centralized data store that will act as the most reliable source, your database in this case.

You can set the corresponding key,value pair in your settings file and use the settings file key, value pair by simply importing it.

But keep in mind, that on every server restart, the settings file key, value pairs will get reset to their default value.

However, you can also write a function that runs on each server restart, that fetches the corresponding database values and populates the settings file values.

```
    In settings file:
    keys = get_keys()

    key_setter.py:
    def get_keys():

        ### Write function as per your requirements ###
```

Now you may simply import "keys" and use them in your views.

When making any change in the database values, make sure your server restarts. Your database must be the only truthful source. You can also add a post save method to the model that updates the settings file value.

I had a similar requirement where I had to dynamically populate the allowed_hosts in the settings file. I achieved this through a function call that fetched certain values from the database. This function would run on each server restart and I also added a post save method to modify the settings file allowed_hosts variable.